# Presenting a View from UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swiftui, uialertcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am creating an iOS app with Xcode. This app asks the user for a text value.

If the user doesn’t know what to type it is possible to press a button to see some examples (full screen view). When the examples view is dismissed the alert is still present so the user types or pastes some text from the examples View.

I created the examples View with SwiftUI and I would navigate to it but I am using an alert so I just have the textfield and the buttons:

```
func openTextValueInputDialog(title:String, message: String, initialValue:String, valueReference:inout String, examplesAvailable:Bool, examplesLinkLabel:String, examplesView:UIViewController)
{

...
...
if (examplesAvailable)
    {
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: examplesLinkLabel, style: .default, handler: {_ in
            
self.present(examplesViewController
                         , animated: true, completion: {})
            
        }))  

  }

...
...

}
```

I should put the navigate instructions in the handler but I just know how to do it in SwiftUI. I had to create this alert that’s not SwiftUI.

Is it possible to navigate to a View?

I could not use View as a parameter because it is not accepted and put UIViewController, that can be "presented" by self.

I am using a SwiftUI View hierarchy, so I would like to know how to launch my examplesView as a UIViewController?

But if another solution exists (using UIKit) I will use it, please put it down here, I shall use it in my app even if it is not SwiftUI.
The examples View has a Text on top, then has a Grid with two columns and one row, containing other text side by side. It is as two Text are one beside the other.